# How do I define a "unary predicate" for copy_if, etc in C++?

Tags: c++, stl

I'm trying to use std::copy_if() and I figured out somewhat how the syntax works from http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/copy_if/ :

```
auto it = std::copy_if (foo.begin(), foo.end(), bar.begin(), [](int i){return !(i<0);} );
```

The last argument is the one that I am confused about. What are the brackets for? Can I use a function I wrote somewhere else as an argument and how would that work? Can I pass another argument to the function if I specify which variable to pass to it?

I guess my overall question is where I could find the syntax for these things. Using this example, I can declare some really simple things, but I'd like to be able to do more with it. I've found a few places that explain what a unary predicate should do and not do, but not actually how to declare one and what that would mean. I'm still somewhat new to the algorithms in c++ and hope to learn how to use them more effectively.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627098/what-is-a-lambda-expression-in-c11

Comment: It's lambda syatax. That's an anonymous function.

Comment: And yes, you can pass all sorts of things to `copy_if`.  They jusyt need to act like a function

Comment: Where can you find the syntax? [Here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda)

Comment: After finding out what it was called, I found this: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can pass anything that behaves like a function as the predicate to `copy_if`.  There are a few common things you can use:

1) Functions

Functions indeed act like functions, so they can be passed as a predicate to `copy_if`:

```
bool is_less_than_zero(int i) { return i < 0; }

int main() {
    std::vector<int> a = {1, 2, -2, -1};
    std::vector<int> b;

    std::copy_if(a.begin(), a.end(), std::back_inserter(b), is_less_than_zero);
    // now b will contain the elements {-2, -1}
}
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2f6cda4b48c6673f)

2) Objects with an overloaded `operator()`

Objects can overload `operator()` so that they act like functions.  These are often called "function objects" or "functors".  This lets you store state, which can't be achieved with raw functions:

```
struct IsLessThan {
    IsLessThan(int i) : i_{i} {}
    bool operator()(int i) { return i < i_; }
    int i_;
};

int main() {
    std::vector<int> a = {1, 2, -2, -1};
    std::vector<int> b;

    std::copy_if(a.begin(), a.end(), std::back_inserter(b), IsLessThan(0));
    // now b will contain the elements {-2, -1}
}
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ebe710222c95412d)

3) [Lambdas](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda)

Lambdas are conceptually anonymous functions.  In reality, they're just syntactic sugar for objects with an overloaded `operator()`, but that makes them a useful tool for creating simple predicates with little code:

```
int main() {
    std::vector<int> a = {1, 2, -2, -1};
    std::vector<int> b;

    std::copy_if(a.begin(), a.end(), std::back_inserter(b),
                 [](int i){ return i < 0; });
    // now b will contain the elements {-2, -1}
}
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e02769c829c4bd58)

Since lambdas are really objects with an overloaded `operator()` they can also contain state, which is given via the lambda's capture list:

```
int main() {
    std::vector<int> a = {1, 2, -2, -1};
    std::vector<int> b;
    int number_to_compare_to = 0;

    std::copy_if(a.begin(), a.end(), std::back_inserter(b),
                 [number_to_compare_to](int i){ return i < number_to_compare_to; });
    // now b will contain the elements {-2, -1}
}
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9ca3c4af2567d556)

There are some facilities in the standard library to easily create function objects that contain state and use it to supply some of the parameters to a function (namely [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind)), but most of the places they were useful it's now easier to use a lambda instead.  That is, the following code creates two objects that both act exactly the same:

```
bool first_less_than_second(int i, int j) { return i < j; }

int main() {
    auto bind_less_than_zero = std::bind(first_less_than_second, std::placeholders::_1, 0);
    auto lambda_less_than_zero = [](int i){ return first_less_than_second(i, 0); };
}
```

In general you should prefer the lambda version, but you will still sometimes see `std::bind` (or its pre-c++11 boost counterpart `boost::bind`) employed.

Comment: Aaah thanks. I was searching forever for 'C++ unary predicate' but it turns out I just had to search 'c++ lambda' and I got a ton of documentation. Good details on what else I can pass to it as well!

Comment: It was really a helpful answer, but being new to c++ , I couldn't understand how you can use struct without initialization , the '0' you provided in 'IsLessThan' struct is for initialization right? But where is the struct object's name? Can I also do it by declaring and initializing a struct object above the copy_If function and then use it inside?

Comment: @Aryaman `IsLessThan(0)` creates a temporary `IsLessThan` object whose lifetime is until the end of the full-expression in which it was created (generally until the next `;` in most cases).  Its no different then the `std::back_inserter(b)` passed as the previous parameter.  If you would rather create a local, named object that's fine (i.e. `IsLessThan less_than_zero(0); std::copy_if(a.begin(), a.end(), std::back_inserter(b), less_than_zero);`)

Comment: @MilesBudnek got it miles, it was a quick reply :)